# $I=\{f\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t] : f(-2,-1,1,2)=0\}$. Generators for $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This problem is from a past qualifying exam I am trying to work on.

I am stuck on trying to find generators for $I$.

The question is as follows

> Let $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t]$ be the polynomial ring with variables $x,y,z,t$ and 
>   let $I=\{f\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t] : f(-2,-1,1,2)=0\}$.
>
> (i) Prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t]$;
>
> (ii) Determine a set of generators for $I$ and justify your answer.

I know how to do the first part. I simply set up the obvious homomorphism,
$f \mapsto f(-2,-1,1,2)$. This is a clear onto ring homomorphism and the kernel
of this map is the given ideal $I$. And by the first isomorphism theorem we are done. But what about the generators for $I$? How should I proceed?

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: You've also got to show that the ideal is maximal.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/I \cong \mathbb{C}$ and since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, the ideal is maximal. right? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** (ii) The ideal generated by $x+2, y+1, z-1, t-2$ is clearly contained in $I$, and then they are equal (why?).

**Edit.** $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t]/(x+2,y+1,z-1,t-2)\simeq\mathbb C$, so the ideal $(x+2,y+1,z-1,t-2)$ is maximal and contained in $I$, therefore they are equal.

Comment: Ok, so one containment is clear. If I call your ideal $J$, then $J \subseteq I$. For the other inclusion, consider $f\in I$. then $f(-2,-1,1,2)=0$ implies that $f=(x+2)(y+1)(z-1)(t-2)q(x,y,z,t)$ for some $q$ and we are done. correct?

Comment: @user54755: How are you getting that all of the generators necessarily divide $f$? Consider $f = x + 2$.

Comment: @YACP: Can you kindly explain a bit more. I've tried, but I don't see it. Is it because $I$ is maximal?

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. Thanks for your time and your help. But I don't immediately see how to show this. I want to work on as many problems as I can before the test. In fact I was happy to see how to find generators in this kind of situation, even if I couldn't prove it fully. I will come back to this if/when I have time. Once again thanks.

Comment: @user54755 Can you show that $R[X]/(X-a)\cong R$ for any commutative ring $R$ and $a\in R$? Then generalize a little and show that $R[X_1,\dots,X_n](X_1-a_1,\dots,X_n-a_n)\cong R$. In your case this shows that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,t]/(x+2,y+1,z-1,t-2)\cong\mathbb C$, so the ideal $(x+2,y+1,z-1,t-2)$ is maximal and contained in $I$, therefore they are equal.